# why XMMatrixInverse() has pDeterminant parameter?

Tags: c++, directx-12

> ```
> XMMATRIX XM_CALLCONV XMMatrixInverse(XMVECTOR *pDeterminant, FXMMATRIX M);
> ```

im just beginning to learn directx, i dont understand why this function also asks for determinant param apart from the original matrix itself to calculate the inverse.

from what i remember on the math part the input matrix alone should be sufficient:

```
orig matrix -> cofactor matrix -> adjoint matrix
orig matrix -> det[orig matrix]
inverse = adjoint/det
```

so why does it need the extra parameter? to speed up calculations, eliminate the 2nd step above?

Comment: From the [really tremendously fine microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/directxmath/nf-directxmath-xmmatrixinverse): _"This parameter can be a nullptr."_. Thus it isn't really _required_.

Comment: i know that, thats not what i asked. i wanted to know why is there at all as an option

Comment: Backwards compatibility maybe? _"Note  For XNAMATH version 2.04 and earlier, the pDeterminant parameter isn't optional. That is, for XNAMATH version 2.04 and earlier, you can't set pDeterminant to a nullptr."_

Comment: It's there as an option in case you want to calculate both the determinant and the inverse. As you noted, calculating the inverse calculates the determinant as a by-product. This lets you receive that by-product, so you don't have to calculate it yourself.

Comment: thank you sir, this finally makes sense now! so its the other way around, i dont supply the actual determinant, only the pointer and the function fills in the xmvector for me. thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

The `XMMatrixInverse` function in [DirectXMath](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMath) uses [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) to compute the inverse. The bulk of the code is computing the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), and the final step is the multiply by the reciprocal of the determinant. Therefore the function also has to compute the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant).

As such, the function optionally returns that determinant in case you have some other use for it. As noted in the comments to your question, the `pDeterminant` was a required out parameter in xboxmath/XNAMath prior to 2.04,

```
XMMATRIX XMMatrixInverse(_Out_ XMVECTOR* pDeterminant, CXMMATRIX M);
```

but I made it optional in DirectXMath as indicated by the [SAL annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/understanding-sal):

```
XMMATRIX XM_CALLCONV XMMatrixInverse(_Out_opt_ XMVECTOR* pDeterminant, _In_ FXMMATRIX M);
```

So you can do:

```
XMMATRIX mat = …

// Don't care about the determinant
XMMATRIX imat = XMMatrixInverse(nullptr, mat);

// Want the determinant
XMVECTOR d;
XMMATRIX imat = XMMatrixInverse(&d, mat);
```

> XNAMath 2.04 was a web-only release that was intended to more closely match some of the changes I had made for DirectXMath to help with the transition from Xbox 360 and the [legacy DirectX SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-). See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/xna-math-version-2-04/).

Since you are new to DirectX, you should take a look at *DirectX Tool Kit* for [DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) / [DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started) and the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for DirectXMath in particular.

Comment: thank you Chuck for detailed explanation! Raymond earlier helped me understand the main idea that it's to be used for an additional optional return value. what is the correct way to initialize the pointer in calling context in case i do want to get the determinant / or not need it, before calling XMMatrixInverse?